# RadEditor.ImageManager not inserting image on clicking Insert

Tags: telerik, radeditor

I have a radEditor control with the ImageManager enabled. this feature worked fine within our last version we had (2011 version) but now with the version we have, the image manager does not insert the image selected. Below is my radEditor html tag:

```
<telerik:RadEditor ID="txtRTE"
SpellCheckSettings-AllowAddCustom="false"
ToolsFile="~/SimpleRTEEditorTools.xml"
OnClientLoad="HandleRTEClientLoad"
ExternalDialogsPath="~/RadControls/EditorDialogs/"
runat="server"
Height="200"
Skin="Default"
EditModes="Design"
AllowScripts="false"
StripFormattingOptions="All">
<ImageManager ViewPaths=".." UploadPaths=".." SearchPatterns="*.jpg,*.gif,*.png" EnableImageEditor="False" ViewMode="Grid" />
```

I am editing the ViewPaths and uploadPaths within the code behind's page_load method:

```
txtRTE.ImageManager.ViewPaths = paths;
txtRTE.ImageManager.UploadPaths = paths;
txtRTE.ImageManager.ContentProviderTypeName = typeof(FolderContentProvider).AssemblyQualifiedName;
```

We implemented our own content provider as seen below:

```
public class FolderContentProvider : FileBrowserContentProvider
    {
        private string ROOT_DIRECTORY_FULL_PATH = 
            //Path to record documents folder
            System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[Constants.RECORD_DOC_ROOT_FOLDER_APP_KEY].ToString() + 
            //folder containing images
            Constants.Record_DOC_FORM_TEXT_IMAGE_FOLDER + "\\" +
            //to get Record ID
            ((MyAppPrincipal)System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal).Record.ID;

         public string RootDirectory
        {
            get
            {
                return ROOT_DIRECTORY_FULL_PATH;
            }
            private set
            {

            }
        }

        private PathPermissions fullPermissions = PathPermissions.Read | PathPermissions.Upload;

        private DirectoryItem[] GetSubDirectories(string path)
        {
            //we have only one directory no sub directories
            //no need to go to file system to find that out
            return new DirectoryItem[0];
        }

        private string GetDirectoryFullPath(string path)
        {
            return RootDirectory;
        }

        private FileItem[] GetFiles(string path)
        {
            string[] filesFullName = Directory.GetFiles(RootDirectory);
            ArrayList files = new ArrayList();
            for (int i = 0; i < filesFullName.Length; i++)
            {
                string fullPath = filesFullName[i];
                System.IO.FileInfo currentFile = new System.IO.FileInfo(fullPath);
                if (IsAlowedFileExtension(currentFile.Extension))
                {
                    string url = string.Format("{0}?path={1}", HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath + "/app/FormTextImageHandler.ashx", currentFile.Name);

                    files.Add(new FileItem(
                        currentFile.Name, //file name
                        currentFile.Extension, //extension
                        currentFile.Length, //size
                        string.Empty,//currentFile.FullName, //location
                        url, //url
                        string.Empty,//tag
                        fullPermissions//permissions
                        )); 
                }
            }
            return (FileItem[])files.ToArray(typeof(FileItem));
        }

        private bool IsAlowedFileExtension(string Extension)
        {
            if (Extension.Equals(".gif", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                return true;
            if (Extension.Equals(".jpg", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                return true;
            if (Extension.Equals(".png", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                return true;
            return false;
        }

        public FolderContentProvider(HttpContext context, string[] searchPatterns, string[] viewPaths, string[] uploadPaths, string[] deletePaths, string selectedUrl, string selectedItemTag)
            : base(context, searchPatterns, viewPaths, uploadPaths, deletePaths, selectedUrl, selectedItemTag)
        {
        }

        public override string DeleteFile(string path)
        {
            //we do not allow removing files
            return null;
        }

        public override string DeleteDirectory(string path)
        {
            //we don't have any sub directories
            //and moreover we don't give delete rights
            return null;
        }

        public override string StoreFile(Telerik.Web.UI.UploadedFile file, string path, string name, params string[] arguments)
        {
            int fileLength = (int)file.InputStream.Length;
            byte[] content = new byte[fileLength];
            file.InputStream.Read(content, 0, fileLength);
            string fullPath = RootDirectory +"\\"+ name;

            FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
            fileStream.Write(content, 0, content.Length);
            fileStream.Flush();
            fileStream.Close();
            return string.Empty;
        }

        public override DirectoryItem ResolveDirectory(string path)
        {
            DirectoryItem[] directories = new DirectoryItem[0];
            FileItem[] files = this.GetFiles(RootDirectory);
            DirectoryItem dir = new DirectoryItem("Images", string.Empty, RootDirectory, string.Empty, fullPermissions, files, directories);
            return dir;
        }

        public override DirectoryItem ResolveRootDirectoryAsTree(string path)
        {
            //we don't have any subdirectories - everythinng is in the same folder
            DirectoryItem[] directories = new DirectoryItem[0];
            FileItem[] files = this.GetFiles(RootDirectory);
            DirectoryItem root = new DirectoryItem("Images", string.Empty, "Images\\", string.Empty, fullPermissions, files, directories);
            return root;
        }

        public override bool CanCreateDirectory
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public override string CreateDirectory(string path, string name)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public override string StoreBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, string url, ImageFormat format)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public override Stream GetFile(string url)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public override string GetPath(string url)
        {
            return RootDirectory;
        }

        public override string GetFileName(string url)
        {
            return null;
        }

        [Obsolete]
        public override DirectoryItem[] ResolveRootDirectoryAsList(string path)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public override bool CheckWritePermissions(string folderPath) {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Any idea's why the old version was able to insert into the field, but the new version is not?

Comment: I have checked with both chrome and IE browser debugging tools to see if there were any errors, but nothing is appearing. there are no server side errors occurring as well.

Answer (score 0):

The FileBrowserProvider API could be changed between the old and new versions. That why my suggestion is to examine the code of the following demo http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/dbfilebrowsercontentprovider/defaultcs.aspx that works as expected and compare it with the code of your custom solution.

If you have any customized dialogs you may need to copy the EditorDialogs folder from the new installation that you are using and customize them from scratch.

Best regards,
Rumen

Comment: thanks, I will try to use my current dlls, and replace them within this project, and see if it gives me the same problem

Comment: Unfortunately, the example within the provided link does not use a custom content provider, where as I am. Any other ideas?

Comment: It does use a custom content provider as stated in the demo description: This example demonstrates the implementation of a custom FileBrowserContentProvider, using a SQL database as a file source. In the offline demos instalation the DBContentProvider class is available in the App_Code\Editor\ folder or in this code library: http://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/aspnet-ajax/file-explorer/connect-radfileexplorer-or-radeditor-to-a-sql-databse.